# Input 0 of layer conv1d_2 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128). To develop LSTM-CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to incorporate a CNN layer into the LSTM network as shown.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1)) model.add(LSTM(128, activation= 'relu')) 
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten()) model.add(Dense(1)) 

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

But it is giving the following error about the input shape. Please help to resolve the issue.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Could you just copy and paste the code here instead of adding links in your question?

Comment: # design network                                                            #
model = Sequential()                                                        #
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu'))   #
model.add(Dropout(0.1))     
model.add(LSTM(128,  activation= 'relu')) 
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))          
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))  
                                       
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size= 1, input_shape = (None, 128, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv1d_12/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d_12/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d_12/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,128], [1,3,128,32].

Comment: It's working fine in my pc. By the way, try changing `kernel_size = 1` in `Conv1D` layer

Comment: It got fixed by changing kernel_size =1

Comment: # design network                                                            #
model = Sequential()                                                        #
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu'))   #
model.add(Dropout(0.1))     
model.add(LSTM(128,  activation= 'relu', return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))          
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))  
                                       
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

Comment: If it fixed your problem, can you please accept the answer by clicking on that tick mark icon on the left?